# How ho handle WindowLeaked?

Tags: java, android

I have WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked in stacktrace and I have to handle it.

**I know reasons why** it appears but fixing it will take too much time.

All I need to **catch** it like typical exception, something like:

```
try {} catch (WindowLeaked e) {}
```

But that doesn't work for sure because it's not `Exception`.

Is there any way to do it?

**I don't ask** **how to fix it** or **what is WindowLeaked**.

The question is: **How can I know that WindowLeak happened?**

Comment: You need to include the code which is causing window leak

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: @shadygoneinsane I dont ask how to fix it. I ask how to **handle it when it happened**

Comment: @waqaslam I dont need because its theoretical question. I want to know how can I catch WindowLeaked in code for **every** possible situation when its happened, not how to fix it in my case.

Comment: `How can I know that WindowLeak happened?` What's the purpose of that? Assuming you knew, what will you do then?

Comment: @azizbekian in my case I have some actions when dialog appears and some actions when it dismissed. So dialog opened -> some actions done -> WindowLeak -> dialog doesnt exist but actions before dismiss are not executed, All I need to handle WindowLeak and execute them manually.

Comment: If you find yourself in a situation, when `WindowLeak` happens, it means you have to redesign your app in the way that it won't happen, and do not come the other way around. It's not an exception that should be caught.

Comment: @azizbekian as I said I know reason why I have WindowLeak, In my case its because Activity is not exists when I try to show dialog after javaRx response. But I have to do tons of checks to fix it. If I catch WindowLeak result will be the same but I will spend less time.

Comment: The answer to your question is that your application cannot "know" when it has happened, and it cannot handle it.  You (the programmer) can know that it has happened (by reading the logcat!) but there is nothing you can do about it ... apart from tracking down the root cause and fixing it.

Comment: @shadygoneinsane WindowLeaked is **not** throws as exception, thats the problem!

Comment: @DEADMC oh yeah i almost forgot -- so your only option here would be that inside your `onStop()` or `onPause()` and `onDestroy()` make sure you dismiss your dialog or if you added a view using window Manager then remove it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that your application cannot "know" when it has happened.  Despite its unconventional name, `android.view.WindowLeaked` is a Java exception.  However, it is uncatchable because it not thrown in any context where there is no application code on the call stack.

(Apparently, it is not thrown at all.  Rather, it seems to be used as a means of capturing a stacktrace for logging.  This does seem rather odd since the stack trace doesn't tell you much ... given that there is no application code on it!)

You (the programmer) can know that it has happened (by reading the logcat!) but there is nothing you can do about it ... apart from tracking down the root cause and fixing it.

Comment: The problem is WindowLeaked is not even thrown. Its created only to show it`s stacktrace to log =( But looks like you are right, there is no way to handle WindowLeaked in code. The one way is analyse logcat while application works and send event after WindowLeaked appeared, but its madness =(

Answer (score 0):

Window Leak exception usually occurs when the user have open the view and didn't close the view.

Comment: I wrote " I know reasons why it appears but fixing it will take too much time." The question is how can I know that it happened in code.

Comment: The only way is that app will crash at some-point when the task will run in the background. And Window leak exception will make the app crash

Comment: WindowLeak cannot make app crash because it doesnt throws as usual exception -.-

Comment: Sometimes window leak make the app crash if we doesn't throw an exception for example if we doesn't close the dialogue it lead the app crash.